# Why after rendering with ffmpeg, file size did not decrease?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, x264, screen-recording, obs

PROBLEM: After rendering a certain video with `ffmpeg` file size increased from 4GB to 6GB.
ORIGINAL VIDEO: [EE1.mkv](https://youtu.be/hcTwh0cGzo4)
FFMPEG COMMAND: `ffmpeg -i EE1.mkv -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -profile:v high out.mp4`
QUESTIONS: Why did the file size increase? What am I doing wrong?

!DETAILS!
After a few years I made about 30 gaming videos (130GB) and with the current covid-19 situation I started recording my online classes (about 40 videos or 150GB). Now because I'm lacking space on my 1TB external HDD I started getting into `ffmpeg`. Before I was only using `obs-studio` and not good parameters for recording.

I was using `CBR` mode for recording, either 5000KB or 15000KB bit rate with varying x264 presets and profiles because I was also experimenting with them. Usually superfast preset with high profile. So I wanted to convert all those videos with `ffmpeg` using `CRF 23`, medium preset and high profile. A note that when I'm recording with `obs-studio` it's set to record in matroska format (`.mkv`).

When I was rendering my online classes videos with these settings I managed to achieve 10x better compression with the same quality. And when rendering my gaming videos I managed to achieve up to 3x better compression with the same quality. However there is this one video that when rendered with the same parameters the file size increases.

The [EE1.mkv](https://youtu.be/hcTwh0cGzo4) should be recorded with `CBR` 15000KB bit rate, with superfast preset and high profile. Also the game that is recorded in this video is `Empire Earth` which needs around 8000KB for it to look good. Everything more than 8000KB is not needed.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: P.S. wait for the video to be processed on youtube!

Comment: Constant Rate Factor (CRF) is rather heuristic (incl. psycho-visual stuff i assume). It's as simple as the docs [say](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264): `By adjusting the so-called quantizer for each frame, it gets the bitrate it needs to keep the requested quality level. The downside is that you can't tell it to get a specific filesize or not go over a specific size or bitrate`. Just because `crf = x` decreases sizes of 9/10 videos for you, it does not mean, that the same happens to video 10/10. Especially, when there is mixed content (different complexity).

Comment: Yes @sascha, you are right about that. However what confuses me is that the original video is at `CBR 15000KB` which means that almost every frame is about that bit rate. So why would the `CRF 23` (or how can it) go over that 15000KB bit rate. Does that mean that if I use for an example `CRF 26` that the quality would remain the same but the file size would be smaller?

Comment: Share full log of conversion attempt with `-t 60` added as an output option.

Comment: Hi @Gyan, this is the [link](https://gist.github.com/ptrra/d97ed6110fa1a1b59b148c59e0561eae) to the log file on github.

Comment: Looks like you're still interested in this old question. Show the "Encoding settings" line from mediainfo output of `EE1.mkv`

Comment: Hi, llogan. Actually I want to answer my own question since I experimented a lot with the `CRF` parameter and I found what I was looking for. Still I would like to know how does `CRF 23` make a bigger file or a bigger bit rate out of `CBR` which was limited at 5000kb.

Answer (score 0):

What I've found as a solution to my problem is:

1. First you need to know your targeted bit rate of the video you want compressed.
   In this case I did this by recording the same game with `CRF 23` and looking what bit rate does it achieve.
2. Then I try to render the `CBR` video with different `CRF` values and I look for those values that achieve similar bit rate to the targeted bit rate.

In this case that was `CRF 32`. Actually this process is a pain, so I'm trying to learn `QP` rate control because maybe it was a better option than `CRF`. I'm still a novice when it comes to `ffmpeg`. Also this case only happens with certain videos that I recorded in `CBR` mode and when I try to render them with `CRF`.